# Reserve ports for modem

Tags: usb, udev, devices, modem

I have a modem with 16 ports used for sending SMS.

When it's connected to my Linux machine, I get 16 ports from `ttyUSB0` to `ttyUSB15`. Currently if I remove this modem and attach another, I get 16 ports from `ttyUSB0` to `ttyUSB15`.

How can I reserve first 16 ports for specific vendor with creating `udev` file, so when I remove this modem and insert another one, it is assigned from `ttyUSB16` onwards?

Edit

My `udev` rule file contents are as follows, which is working, but port number changes everytime I replug.

```
Name=="Future Technology Devices International,Ltd",SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6011", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", SYMLINK="Ketan%b", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-15]*", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB1",
```

Output

```
ls -l /dev/K*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 2013-01-08 15:09 /dev/Ketan-8.1 -> ttyUSB1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 2013-01-08 15:09 /dev/Ketan-8.2 -> ttyUSB5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 2013-01-08 15:09 /dev/Ketan-8.3 -> ttyUSB11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 2013-01-08 15:09 /dev/Ketan-8.4 -> ttyUSB12
```

Here ports are 16, but they are divided in group of four.
`ttyUSB` `1`,`5`,`11`,`12` values are changing every time I plug a modem.

Comment: Does unbuffer udevadm monitor --environment | grep 'ID_SERIAL=' output different serial numbers for both modems when detaching/attaching it?

Answer (score 3):

If you loosen the requirement for using `ttyUSB0` - `ttyUSB31`, then you may just have a possibility. What I've done is let `udev` create symlinks to the device nodes assigned by the kernel. You cannot reliably hardwire a physical device to use `ttyUSB0`, you can however reliably add a symlink `ttyUSB001` to point to whichever device node you want. The trick here is that the kernel will never assign a device node a name that starts with `ttyUSB0..`, except for exactly `ttyUSB0` itself. This trick therefore works for max 99 devices, but it can easily be changed to 4 digits (and 999 devices), as long as the first digit remains `0`.

For this to work, you have to be able to uniquely identify both modems. Check if they have unique serial numbers by running this command while unplug/plug the device:

```
unbuffer udevadm monitor --environment | grep 'ID_SERIAL='
```

I don't know your modem, but this is the `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-serial.rules` file that I have been using to uniquely identify each of my Arduino's:

```
ACTION!="add", GOTO="persistent_serial_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="tty", GOTO="persistent_serial_end"
KERNEL!="ttyUSB[0-9]*", GOTO="persistent_serial_end"

# This is old 11.10 style: IMPORT="usb_id --export %p"
IMPORT{builtin}="path_id"
ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="04fc_RS232C_to_USB_Adapter"    , SYMLINK="multimeter"                                       , OWNER="jhendrix"
ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A800FERY" , SYMLINK="arduinoMega1280-001"       , SYMLINK+="ttyUSB001" , OWNER="jhendrix"
ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A900F4EF" , SYMLINK="arduinoMega1280-002"       , SYMLINK+="ttyUSB002" , OWNER="jhendrix"
ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A900f3Kr" , SYMLINK="arduinoDuemilanove168-003" , SYMLINK+="ttyUSB003" , OWNER="jhendrix"

LABEL="persistent_serial_end"
```

Of course you have to replace a few things like `OWNER`, which is the user to which the devices are assigned and `ENV{ID_SERIAL}` which can be found by:

```
unbuffer udevadm monitor --environment | grep 'ID_SERIAL='
```

And last but not least the various `SYMLINK`s should be replaced by the exact name you want to use. This file makes any of my Arduino's available under three names (eg.):

```
/dev/ttyUSB0             # dynamic, assigned by kernel upon plugging the device
/dev/arduinoMega1280-002 # static,  symlink -> ttyUSB0
/dev/ttyUSB002           # static,  symlink -> ttyUSB0 , this is what you are asking for.
```

Check my [private wiki article on this for more details](http://wirespeed.xs4all.nl/mediawiki/index.php/Udev_rules_file_for_Arduino_boards).

Comment: As I create my rule file SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303", ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b", SYMLINK="Ketan%b", KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", MODE="0666", works but I am not getting fix ports, I used your trick not working. All is well in my conf. But The port number changes everytime. I need to fix it.

Comment: Please share your file in your question.