# Fixed udev rules for USB modems

Tags: usb, udev, modem

On gentoo I have 10 USB modems and every of them has 3 interfaces /dev/ttyUSB0, 1, 2 and so on for each modem. Sometimes their positions can change, so it is very difficult to work with them.

I'm working with each modem first interface. So for first modem it would be ttyUSB0, other ttyUSB1 and ttyUSB2 I don't need for sending commands to modem.

How can I write static udev rules for each of them so they would have fixed position, and how could I rename ttyUSB0 in something like modem-xxxxxxx interface for easier working with them ?

lsusb output:

```
client dev # lsusb
Bus 002 Device 039: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
```

dmesg output for one of the huawei modems:

```
[166041.393547] usb 2-6: default language 0x0409
[166041.402548] usb 2-6: udev 40, busnum 2, minor = 167
[166041.402552] usb 2-6: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1001
[166041.402555] usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[166041.402558] usb 2-6: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[166041.402660] usb 2-6: usb_probe_device
[166041.402664] usb 2-6: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[166041.405566] usb 2-6: adding 2-6:1.0 (config #1, interface 0)
[166041.408589] option 2-6:1.0: usb_probe_interface
[166041.408593] option 2-6:1.0: usb_probe_interface - got id
[166041.408600] option 2-6:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[166041.408803] usb 2-6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[166041.408835] usb 2-6: adding 2-6:1.1 (config #1, interface 1)
[166041.411572] option 2-6:1.1: usb_probe_interface
[166041.411576] option 2-6:1.1: usb_probe_interface - got id
[166041.411581] option 2-6:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[166041.411683] usb 2-6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[166041.411703] usb 2-6: adding 2-6:1.2 (config #1, interface 2)
[166041.414572] option 2-6:1.2: usb_probe_interface
[166041.414576] option 2-6:1.2: usb_probe_interface - got id
[166041.414580] option 2-6:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[166041.414682] usb 2-6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[166041.414714] hub 2-0:1.0: state 7 ports 10 chg 0000 evt 0040
```

Tried to find port addresses like this:

```
client rules.d # udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
```

then created file /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules and wrote there lines like this:

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", KERNELS=="2-6:1.0", NAME="ttyUSB0_654"
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", KERNELS=="2-6:1.1", NAME="ttyUSB1_654"
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", KERNELS=="2-6:1.2", NAME="ttyUSB2_654"
```

but looks like it's not working.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60286/reserve-ports-for-modem http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60154/udev-rule-file-for-modem-not-working

Comment: The output of `udevadm info -q all -n /dev/ttyUSB0` would be useful, to see what you can filter on.

Comment: Your requested output is here: http://pastebin.com/vWSCdbNB

Comment: According to your pastebin, you already have a `/dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:02.0-usb-0:5:1.0-port0` ... does that work for you?

Comment: At this moment I pluged in one modem into box, for easier debugging. It's position is /dev/ttyUSB0, /dev/ttyUSB1 and /dev/ttyUSB2, if i will plug another 9 modems their poisitions could change. But i need to pshisicaly tell linux what modem would be mapped for ttyUSBX port.

Comment: Did you check that /dev/serial/by-path/... symlink? That link should always point to the first port on the modem plugged in to that given USB port. If you plug in a second modem, it'll get a different link there. You should be able to use that file in place of /dev/ttyUSB0.

Comment: @derobert In first comment you posted two links. I've already tried solutions that was there, but could not get things working. Also i tried to fix my problem reading this topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49910/how-to-distinguish-between-identical-usb-to-serial-adapters

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8004/discussion-between-derobert-and-user777)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some [discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8004) it appears that that symlinks already exist in `/dev/serial/by-path/` and will work.