# udev rules for USB serial 'by path' not working

Tags: udev, serial-port, usb-device, ttyusb

I have more than 2 serial devices enumerated by FTDI driver as `/dev/ttyUSB0`, `/dev/ttyUSB1`, `/dev/ttyUSB2` etc. On reboot, these may get jumbled up in any other order. Also, I may replace/swap these devices physically among these or with some other similar device.

Now, I want a persistent enumeration for these. I want the device names to be enumerated according to the physical USB port (I may connect to the USB ports on the motherboard of the PC directly or use a USB hub) that the device is connected to - say if the devices are connected to the USB hub, port 1 should be reserved to named as `ttyUSB0`, port 2 as `ttyUSB1` and so on.

After some basic reading, I figured (as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68588/fixed-udev-rules-for-usb-modems)) that `/dev/serial/by-path/` lists the devices as sort of a symlink. So, I created a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/101-usb-serial.rules` with the following:

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio", PATH=="pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:10.1:1.0", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB000"
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio", PATH=="pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:10.2:1.0", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB001"
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio", PATH=="pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:10.3:1.0", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB002"
```

But this doesn't work. On doing `ls /dev/ttyUSB*` I'm unable to see the new symlinks I have created. What could possibly be going wrong?

Comment: There is no PATH key. Look at the output for `udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0` while it is plugged in. You can then probably use the `ID_PATH` value. Since this is prefixed by `E:` you need to look for it with `ENV{...}`.

Comment: I tried replacing `PATH` with `ENV{ID_PATH}`. It didn't work as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking cues from the comment above I managed to find a solution to the above.

```
udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0 | grep "ID_PATH="
```

The above lists the the sysfs path for the port that `/dev/ttyUSB0` is connected to. Use this value to create rules for as many devices (`ttyUSB1`, `ttyUSB2`....) as you want in the rules file, say `/etc/udev/rules.d/101-usb-serial.rules` as follows:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty",ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:10.1:1.0",SYMLINK+="ttyUSB001"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty",ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:10.2:1.0",SYMLINK+="ttyUSB002"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty",ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:10.3:1.0",SYMLINK+="ttyUSB003"
```

Once done making changes or creating the file, run the following:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

**P.S.** : The above example scenario (the one that I am using) is using a 4-port Belkin USB hub. `Device 1` is connected to the `port 1` of the hub `Device 2` is connected to the `port 2` and so on.

Comment: The answer from @skrowten_hermit is correct, with one caveat: Using filename `101-...` forces the rule to be fired in the beginning. This will not work, as `ID_PATH` is not available yet. Please ensure you add this rule using filename `99-usb-serial.rules`. The ID_PATH environment variable is set by `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules` `IMPORT{builtin}="path_id"`, so the custom rule must be fired after that one.