# Get the USB port 'by path' to autofill in udev rules file

Tags: udev, usb-device, ttyusb, usb-audio

I'm trying to improve on my [udev rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541156/udev-rules-for-usb-serial-by-path-not-working) for USB serial devices or USB sound cards. I want the USB port number to be populated in the `ENV{ID_PATH}` field without having to edit it myself (this becomes useful if I'm copying this rules file to a different PC for example). I know that I can write a bash script to parse the result of (in case of serial devices)

```
udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0 | grep "ID_PATH="
```

or by parsing the result of (in case of sound devices)

```
udevadm monitor --kernel --subsystem-match=sound
```

to get the value and write it to the rules file.

But I got more interested in the `RUN` and `PROGRAM` fields. I did come across examples like [this](https://www.pcsuggest.com/run-shell-scripts-from-udev-rules/) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-to-run-custom-scripts-upon-usb-device-plug-in) where an external service/script is called, but none write back to any field within the rules file itself. I'm wondering if it is even possible that I can run a script and fill the value of the key `ENV{ID_PATH}` with the sysfs path (like a self-configuring or self-learning rules file)? Does `udev` provide such a functionality? If yes, how can I do it?